# IE 7 Z-Index and IE6 Fixed Positioning

Tags: css

I have a vertical scrolling website - It works fine in IE7 aside from a few margin issues and problems rendering some .PNGS - but I have one big problem;

I'm using two fixed positioned menus - one that slides out at an anchor point and one that just sticks to the bottom. Essentially - ones always at the top with the scroll and ones always at the bottom.

They stick, and work fine - problem is, I'm using z-index in the CSS and it seems IE7 is having some problems with it - **with IE7 the sticky menus go behind the content.** I read a suggestion trying to position it to 'relative'. But that would destroy the fixed.

Any suggestions? Thanks for anything -

Sub Question - of less importance, as I'm no longer carrying IE6 - but, is there a way to continue using these menus for IE6 - a way to work around it not reading position: fixed?

Here's an image to illustrate the problem better. http://tinypic.com/r/20fqqkp/7

Comment: Please provide relevant markup/css. Also, providing a http://jsfiddle.net/ is useful.

Comment: I will as soon as possible - the code is intertwined with a lot of other code and I need to pick out all relevant code - once I do so I'll put it in a fiddle for this question to continue. I have just added a Graphic link above to help illustrate in the mean while - cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the zindex fix http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

Comment: Rad - a little progress. I plugged in the script they provided there, and it did help some - but seemed to pull some of my background image to scroll in front of the content as well - any suggestions on customizing the script to fix something like that?

Comment: As the relation to what some element is now positioned has changed, this can indeed happen. I think there are two solutions: 1) You could try to do it manually by applying a position relative + z-index to all parent elements of the absolutely positioned element and only fix these elements. 2) Or you try to start where you are now, and position each parent container correctly. | As I do not know your exact problem, it's a bit hard to guess on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Without any code it's tough to know for certain, but most likely the issue you are seeing is the [z-index bug](http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html) in IE.

Any element in IE6 or IE7 with `position: relative` set will generate a new stacking context.  This means that the z-index of their elements not in the same stacking context won't necessarily stack as you'd expect.

For example, consider this HTML:

```
<div id="parent-1">
    <div id="child-1"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent-2">
    <div id="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
/* Both parents create their own stacking context */
#parent-1, #parent-2 {
  position: relative;
}

#child-1, #child-2 {
  position: fixed;      
}

/* Should be lower */
#child-1 {
  z-index: 10;      
}

/* Should be higher */
#child-2 {
  z-index: 20;      
}
```

According to the spec, `#child-2` should always be stacked higher than `#child-1` (and this is what you'll see in sane browsers).  But since both parents have `position: relative` set, IE6-7 will have created 2 stacking contexts and might not do this for you.

The fix is to apply `z-index` to the elements creating the stacking contexts or to make sure all elements are in the same stacking context.

As for your IE6 problem, yes, you can emulate it with [CSS expressions](http://annevankesteren.nl/test/examples/ie/position-fixed.html).  Use the following in an [IE6 only](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) stylesheet:

```
/* Fixed to the top */
#top-fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: expression(document.documentElement.scrollTop);    
}

/* Fixed to the bottom */
#bottom-fixed {
  position:absolute;
  top:expression(
     document.documentElement.scrollTop +  
     document.documentElement.clientHeight - 
     this.clientHeight
  );
}
```

Comment: Please do not suggest expressions in IE. They perform rather poorly on a browser, that is due to it's age often on it's limits. They fire more often than you might think and can drag the performance of a page down. It is way better to position the elements with plain javascript and maybe do a bit of throttling (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) to give IE some time to breathe.

Comment: @topek 100% agree about expressions and performance, but if the user is on IE6 to begin with, I suspect they're used to the internet running like sludge.

Comment: I agree that the an IE user does not get a fast browsing experience per definitionem. But one should not worsen the situation by being lazy and using an expression instead of 10min more work for a javascript solution.